# T-SQL ORDER BY varchar field

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

Here is my current query..

```
SELECT invNumber FROM invs ORDER BY invNumber DESC
```

..and result is:

```
1032-IN1
1032
1031-IN1
1031
1030-IN4
1030-IN3
1030-IN2
1030-IN1
1030
1029
```

Expected result is:

```
1032
1032-IN1
1031
1031-IN1
1030
1030-IN1
1030-IN2
1030-IN3
1030-IN4
1029
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Will the value of the left **always** be a 4 digit string? Also, could you have `'1030-IN10`? It seems like you should have the 3 parts split into different columns, in my opinion.

Comment: @Larnu No. Both left value and value after the `IN` are an incremental numbers

Comment: so its incremental but duplicated?

Comment: @metal Yes. These identifiers are for parent and child. For example,  `1030-IN1` to `1030-IN4` are child records of `1030`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try a two-tiered sort here:

```
SELECT invNumber
FROM invs
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN invNumber LIKE '%-%'
         THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(invNumber, 1, CHARINDEX('-', invNumber)-1) AS INT)
         ELSE CAST(invNumber AS INT) END DESC,
    invNumber;
```

The first level of sorting checks if the invoice number contains a dash component.  If it *does*, then we substring off the number only and cast to integer.  Otherwise, if the invoice number be a pure number, we just cast right away.  The second level of sorting uses `invNumber` directly, to break the tie, should one occur.

Comment: You miss `DESC` there.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, Thanks for the answer and the nice explanation. This solution works as a charm.

Comment: @Bishan But keep in mind that if you really wanted fast performance while sorting, you might consider having a separate int column for the invoice number, and a text column for the suffix.

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned, it sounds like you need to normalise your data. The reason you're getting the sort order you have is because you're expecting strings to sort in the same order as a numerical data type; where that simply isn't true. A value like `'2'` is **greater than** `'10'` with strings.

I would split the values into 3 parts, and `CAST`/`CONVERT` them before ordering. There is likely a better way here, but it's the way I got to the logic in the end:

```
SELECT YT.YourColumn
FROM (VALUES('1032-IN1'),
            ('1032'),
            ('1031-IN1'),
            ('1031'),
            ('1030-IN4'),
            ('1030-IN3'),
            ('1030-IN2'),
            ('1030-IN1'),
            ('1030'),
            ('1029'))YT(YourColumn)
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('-',YT.YourColumn),0)))CI(h)
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES(TRY_CONVERT(int,LEFT(YT.YourColumn,ISNULL(CI.h-1,LEN(YT.YourColumn)))),STUFF(YT.YourColumn,1,CI.h,'')))V(Incremental,RightPart)
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES(LEFT(V.RightPart,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',V.Rightpart)-1),TRY_CONVERT(int,STUFF(V.RightPart,1,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',V.Rightpart)-1,''))))R([In],InNo)
ORDER BY V.Incremental DESC, R.[In], R.InNo DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering different datatypes, this solution will help.

```
select [invNumber] from invs 
order by left([invNumber], (case when charindex([invNumber], '-') > 1 then charindex([invNumber], '-')-1 else len([invNumber]) end)) desc, 
        right([invNumber], case when charindex([invNumber], '-') > 1 then len([invNumber]) - charindex([invNumber], '-') else
               len([invNumber]) end) asc
```